# Subpages Menu - obtain field subtitel instead of nav_title

Tags: typo3, typoscript, submenu, fluid

I would appreciate support with the following problem:
in old times (before FLUID) it was possible to extract the value of field subtitle instead of nav_title for a ***menu with subpages*** with:

```
tt_content.menu.20.1.1.NO {   
    stdWrap.cObject = COA
    stdWrap.cObject {
      10 = TEXT
      10.field = subtitle // nav_title
    }    
}
```

How is it possible to get the same result with FLUID?
I have tried:

```
tt_content.menu_subpages.dataProcessing {
  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
  10.titleField = subtitle // nav_title
}
```

and

```
tt_content.menu_subpages.dataProcessing.10.titleField = subtitle // nav_title
```

but it doesn't work out. Output is still default nav_title (although fields subtitle of all subpages **have** a value)

Thanks for support!

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `fluid` template. there you have access to the whole `pages` record.

What you need is something like:

```
{f:if(condition:page.subtitle, then:page.subtitle, else:page.nav_title)}
```

or:

```
{f:if(condition:page.subtitle, then:page.subtitle, else:'{f:if(condition:page.nav_title, then:page.nav_title, else:page.title)}')}
```

Comment: Hi Bernd,
thanks for you suggestions. Is there any way to resolve this with TypoScript?
As for you FLUID solution I would need further advice as I am not that professional with FLUID. Where do I have to make the changes and how? You mentioned _"the whole pages record"_. This part: **_/Ressorces/Private/TemplatesMenuSubpages.html_**?

Comment: if you are using the menuprocessor, you are preparing data to be used in Fluid. there is no rendering in typoscript. and I doubt you could change data on the fly.

Comment: you should get familiar with Fluid templates. it is more flexible and more intuitive than typoscript. therefor Fluid will be used more and more. And it's a nice system where you redefine just those files you want to be changed. All other files will be used from the original place. in typoscript you define the fallback list and prepare variables to use in Fluid (in your case the whole data for your menu. all involved pages and all their properties). [Start Doc to Fluid](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

In setup.typoscript (Typo3 9.5.x and 10.4.x)

```
page{
    10 {
        dataProcessing.10.titleField = subtitle // title
    }
}
```

The variable path (page.10.dataProcessing) depends on your setup.